# Close Browser Even when Publish the Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, publish

I'm trying to close the browser using asp.net … I tried so many ways it's working but when I publish the Project It's not working any Idea to solve the problem ??

The Ways I Used >>>

```
        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "test", "javascript:window.open('','_self','');window.close();", True)
        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();")


        'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>self.close();</script>")


        'Dim TskKill_Chrome As New ProcessStartInfo("Taskkill.exe")
        'TskKill_Chrome.Arguments = "/F /IM Chrome.exe /T"
        'Process.Start(TskKill_Chrome)

        'Dim TskKill_Edge As New ProcessStartInfo("Taskkill.exe")
        'TskKill_Edge.Arguments = "/F /IM MSEdge.exe /T"
        'Process.Start(TskKill_Edge)


        Dim AllProcesses As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
        For Each process In AllProcesses
            If process.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then
                Dim name As String = process.ProcessName
                If name = "iexplore" OrElse name = "msedge" OrElse name = "firefox" OrElse name = "chrome" Then
                    process.CloseMainWindow()
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are trying to close the browser from your website? If thats what you are asking, then that is not possible. Imagine the frustration if you went to a website and it suddenly would close your whole browser.

Comment: yes, you got it ... at least I want to Close the current tab (my website) after finishing a specific function

Comment: You can't close the main tab, loaded by the user. You could destroy it's content or replace it with another page saying something like "you have successfully logged out". You may be able to close a child window from its parent provided the child window it is not cross origin.